# How do I check the TURN Server logs?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, stun

I have installed the open source TURN server(rfc5766-turn-server), I run it using the following command
`sudo turnserver -L my.domain.in -a -b /usr/local/etc/turnuserdb.conf -f -r domain.in`

This is the output I get in terminal,

```
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Citrix-3.1.5.0 'Arch Lector'
0:

==== Show them the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL is not supported
0: OpenSSL version: fresh enough
0: TURN Network Engine version: 2.5

=====================================================

0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0: ERROR: Cannot add a listener address: qeee.rtbi.in
0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0:
CONFIG: --no-udp-relay: UDP relay endpoints are not allowed.
0: ===========Discovering listener addresses: =========
0: Listener address to use: 127.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: 10.7.3.129
0: Listener address to use: 203.134.253.129
0: Listener address to use: 10.0.0.1
0: Listener address to use: ::1
0: =====================================================
0: ===========Discovering relay addresses: =============
0: Relay address to use: 10.7.3.129
0: Relay address to use: 10.0.0.1
0: =====================================================
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:49500
0: turn server id=2 created
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:49501
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 10.7.3.129:49500
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 10.7.3.129:49501
0: turn server id=3 created
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 203.134.253.129:49500
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 203.134.253.129:49501
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 10.0.0.1:49500
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 10.0.0.1:49501
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:49500
0: IPv6. TCP listener opened on : ::1:49501
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll
0: IO method (cli thread): epoll
0: turn server id=1 created
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766`
```

when a client is connected or using this TURN server, will I get any log in my terminal or anywhere else?

Comment: You should actually post this message to the rfc5766-Turn-Server mailing list. The author of the code, a few other helpful folks (and occasionally me), are quick to answer.

Comment: Got it working suddenly some days back!!

Comment: How did you get it working ?

Answer (score 6):

Also this is an very old question, I think it is still not properly answered yet!
There are indeed log files under `var/log/` but they are not very helpful.

CoTurn logs to the syslog! So you need to run

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep turnserver
```

to see what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

The default path of log seems to be:

```
/var/log/turn_*.log
```

Comment: How do we know if only STUN or STUN and TURN was used by looking at the logs?