# Coturn log file not found

Tags: turn, coturn

I have set the log file inside turnserver.conf and also restarted the Coturn server but the log file is not generated.

Here is the turnserver.conf log config

```
log-file=/var/log/turnserver.log
simple-log
```

The file turnserver.log is not generated in the /var/log directory. When I scanned through the directory, I only found a file named turnserver.log.bk. Is the log file not being generated due to lack of writing permission, or any other causes?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check in
`cat /var/log/syslog | grep turnserver`
Asked and answered here:
[How do I check the TURN Server logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719932/how-do-i-check-the-turn-server-logs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That could be a permission issue. When you define the `log-file`, you must create that file in that location and also set write permissions for the `turnserver` user.

Creating and setting permissions:

```bash
sudo install -o turnserver -g turnserver -m 644 /dev/null /var/log/turnserver.log
```

Then, Restart the coturn service:

```bash
sudo service coturn restart
```

Make sure service is running:

```bash
sudo service coturn status
```

Then you will be able to watch the log file:

```bash
sudo tail -f /var/log/turnserver.log
```

See for more info: [How to install Coturn](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/faq.html#how-to-install-coturn)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions to turnserver worked for me.

```
sudo chown turnserver:turnserver /var/log/turnserver.log
```